# Need to store the data in Binary format for the Uploaded file using RADUPLOAD

Tags: c#, radupload

Here is the code I tried to store the data in binary format for the uploaded file...................

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
int PartyRowId = 0;
foreach (UploadedFile file in AsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles)

{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
    string json3 = "{'value1':" + value+ ",'value2':" + value+ ",'value3':" + value+ ",'PartyDoc':" + bytes + "}";

}
}
```

i got the Json as

```
 {'value1':0,'value2':0,'value3':0,'PartyDoc':System.Byte[]}
```

not able to retrieve the binary data Please help me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Convert.ToBase64String();`

```
string json3 = "{'value1':" + value+ ",'value2':" + value+ ",'value3':" + value+ ",'PartyDoc':" + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) + "}";
```

Then on the other side you can use`Convert.FromBase64String();`

Comment: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Answer (score 0):

done with the conversion as below...

CONVERT(varbinary(100), CONVERT(varchar(max),@variable))

Comment: sql server.it is inserting when I am done at Executing stored procedure...but when I am trying to insert from Application Scenario....